# Is there a way to disable multiple buttons at one time?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a vba userForm that has 36 buttons on it.  I would like to disable all buttons when a value on one of my spreadshets reaches a certain number.  Right now with each click of a button a number goes up by one on the spreadsheet I'm referencing.  When the number reaches three I would like to disable all buttons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Dim oCtrl As Control
Dim oButton As CommandButton

For Each oCtrl In MyForm.Controls
    If oCtrl.Tag = "SomeValue" Then
        Set oButton = oCtrl
        oButton.Enabled = False
    End If
Next

Set oCtrl = Nothing
Set oButton = Nothing
```

If you have other buttons which you do not want disabled, the solution is to use the Tag property. Set the Tag property on all the buttons which you will want to enable or disable together to the same value. Then you can check for that value in a look and enable/disable them. Another way is to name them the same prefix or suffix and check for that in your code.

**Addition**

<strike>Btw, the Control object does not have an Enabled property. So you must "cast" it to a CommandButton to disable it</strike>. Apparently a Control object does have an Enabled property but it does not show in intellisense. However, you should still try to cast the Control to a CommandButton to ensure that's what you have. Here's an expanded version:

```
Dim oCtrl As Control
Dim oButton As CommandButton

For Each oCtrl In MyForm.Controls
    If oCtrl.Tag = "SomeValue" Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set oButton = oCtrl
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not oButton Is Nothing Then
            oButton.Enabled = False
        End If
    End If
Next

Set oCtrl = Nothing
Set oButton = Nothing
```

Comment: Due to the limitations of VBA, I've found the .Tag property to be just about the most useful item in VBA.  :)

Comment: @Stewbob - Yes going back many iterations of VB, the tag property is nearly essential for many operations like this. That said, formal VB (e.g. VB6, VB5 etc) had the concept of a control array which would be ideal in this situation as you could act on the entire array at once.

Comment: Yeah, Control Arrays were great.  I was sad to see them go....  You can actually access the .Enabled property on a Control object, even though it doesn't show up in Intellisense.  If the Control you are referencing actually has the .Enabled property, the code runs, if the .Enabled property doesn't exist for that type, the code crashes.  It's pretty sloppy programming, but it works if you are careful of the type of objects you are using.

Comment: @Stewbob - Hmm. Didn't realize the Control object Enabled property existed. I've updated my post given that info.

Answer (score 5):

Place all the buttons in a Frame object, then just disable the entire frame.  This will also disable everything inside the frame.

Alternatively, based on your last question, you could use this code:

```
Dim counter As Integer

Private Sub btn1_Click()
    CaptureImage (btn1.Name)
End Sub

Private Sub btn2_Click()
    CaptureImage (btn2.Name)
End Sub

Private Sub btn3_Click()
    CaptureImage (btn3.Name)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    counter = 1
End Sub

Private Sub CaptureImage(ByVal btnName As String)
    Controls("capture" & counter).Picture = Controls(btnName).Picture
    counter = counter + 1
    If counter > 3 Then
        DisableButtons
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DisableButtons()
    Dim ctl As Control
    For Each ctl In UserForm1.Controls
        If Left(ctl.Name, 3) = "btn" Then
            ctl.Enabled = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Ideally, you would want to cast the Control objects to Buttons like Thomas suggests.

Comment: Do I need to place this code in a certain spot for it to work?  I'm also trying to understand your code.  Does it determine when an image has been placed in the last label, then it disables?

Comment: @Mike, I've edited my answer to show the entire code that you could use based on this question and your last, related question (minus the other 33 btn_Click subroutines).

Answer (score 0):

@Mike: Try --

```
If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = 3 Then 
    UserForm1.CommandButton1.Enabled = True 
Else 
    UserForm1.CommandButton1.Enabled = False 
End If
```

(Replace `Sheet1`, `A1`, `UserForm1` and `CommandButton1` with the correct ones for your workbook)

Comment: You stated CommandButton6, is this just disabling one button?  I have 36 to disable.

Comment: @Mike: I think a combination of @Stewbob's suggestion and the above code (substituting `CommandButton` for `Frames(1)`) could do the trick.